# Angular directive not getting called when scope is updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a scope that is modifying a variable:

```
$scope.showContext = function(context) {
        $scope.currentContext = context;
....
}
```

I have a directive on the page:

```
<div org-chart workflow="currentContext" />
```

I have a directive:

```
var OrgChartDirective = function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict : 'AE',
        scope : {
            workflow : '=',
        },
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {


            if (scope.workflow != null) {
                console.log("**________________________________**");
                console.log(scope);
            } else {
                alert("Workflow is null");
            }
      ....
```

When I load the page, I get the alert that the workflow is null.

When I run the scope function that updates `$scope.currentContext`, nothing else happens.  It should be called again, right?

Edited to say: I have this on the page and it does show that the variable is getting set after I call the scope method:

> > Workflow----> {{currentContext.workflow}}

Comment: Can you show the directive code ?

Comment: It's there, formatting was bad

Comment: use a watch in directive or create an event that broadcasts from controller to directive to notify of scope change. What are you trying to do with `workflow` in `link`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to watch/observe for the property change in the link function like this:

```
attrs.$watch('workflow', function() {
    //do whatever logic you want
});
```

Read more about observers and watchers and how you can use them here: 
[Ben naddal tutorial on observers and watchers](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2449-directive-link-observe-and-watch-functions-execute-inside-an-angularjs-context.htm)

Try this gist: [Gist for observers and watchers](https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/6282750)

Comment: What, then, is the point of the scope "=" (and "&" and "@", for that matter)?  I thought that it was to keep the data synchronized between the 2 scopes (for "=", anyway).  Are you saying that it keeps it updated but does not re-run the directive when it changes in the "parent" or "original" scope?

Comment: You will have to watch for the changes. Have a look on gist link I have given. This will help you to understand better.

Answer (score 1):

Defering to charlietfi, try with a watcher

```
link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
  scope.$watch('workflow', function(val) {
  ...
  });
```

Comment: OP is using isolated scope , `$watch` on scope would make more sense. The attribute won't change